# many to many relationship on the same class

Tags: grails, grails-orm

As the title states, I need to tell grails GORM that a domain class has a many to many relationship to itself.
In my system, I have a class "course", this "course" class can have none, one or many correlatives.
Taking the example:

mathematical analysis 2

- To be able to take the mathematical analysis 2 course, you need to have approved mathematical analysis 1 and physics courses.
- mathematical analysis 1 does not have any correlatives or courses to be approved to be able to anyone to take the course.

I have the following:

```
class Course {
    String name
    static hasMany = [correlatives: Course]
    static belongsTo = [target_course: Course]
}
```

But it does not seem to have the impact in the Data base that I expect.

Im expecting to have a course_course table that has the many to many to itself like the following:

```
course_course
int id_course_course
int id_correlative_course 
int id_target_course
```

Am I missing something important here?, help please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a many to many table to represent that.  While each `Course` may "have many" correlatives, each correlated course only has one parent.

This is sufficiently represented by a single table like (heavily depending on any mappings you specify):

```
course:
    id (int)
    name (varchar)
    target_course_id (int, nullable)
```

Comment: Thank you!, is it possible to access a list of the many correlatives courses from a course object?

Comment: Absolutely!  You have a `correlatives` field in `Course`.  So if you had `Course a`, you could just access this as `a.correlatives`.  Any named `hasMany` automatically exists as a field like this...by default it's a `Set` (I think) but you can override to any collection type you need.

Comment: Thank you man!, Grails Documentation is so simplistic it sometimes gets confusing.